# Python: multidimensional array masking

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, multidimensional-array, masking

What is equivalent pythonic implementation for the following simple piece of code in Matlab.

**Matlab:**

```
B = 2D array of integers as indices [1...100]
A = 2D array of numbers: [10x10]
A[B] = 0
```

which works well as for example for `B[i]=42` it finds the position `2` of column `5` to be set.
In **Python** it causes an ***error: out of bound*** which is **logical**. However to translate the above Matlab code into Python we are looking for pythonic ways.
Please also consider the problem for higher dimensions such as:

```
B = 2D array of integers as indices [1...3000]
C = 3D array of numbers: [10x10x30]
C[B] = 0
```

One way we thought about it is to reform indices array elements as `i,j` instead of being absolute position. That is, position `42` to `divmod(42,m=10)[::-1] >>> (2,4)`. So we will have a `nx2 >>> ii,jj` vectors of indices which can be used for indexing `A` easily.
We thought that it might be a better way, efficient also for higher dimensions in **Python**.

Comment: "In Python it causes an error: out of bound which is logical"... what causes this? Can you show what you've tried in Python?

Comment: Why are you using a 2D array as the index of another 2D array?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves As mentioned in the question, A.shape = (10,10) so indexing by A[42] is not legal! This is not the case for Matlab code since it automatically matches 42 to row 2 and column 4.

Comment: @FlopCoder Because I am translating an already-written code. I like Python logic here which is `true` to cause error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.ravel()` on the array (A) before indexing it, and then `.reshape()` after.

Alternatively, since you know `A.shape`, you can use `np.unravel_index` on the other array (B) before indexing.

Example 1:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.ones((5,5), dtype=int)
>>> B = [1, 3, 7, 23]
>>> A
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> A_ = A.ravel()
>>> A_[B] = 0
>>> A_.reshape(A.shape)
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Example 2:

```
>>> b_row, b_col = np.vstack([np.unravel_index(b, A.shape) for b in B]).T
>>> A[b_row, b_col] = 0
>>> A
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

---

Discovered later: you can use `numpy.put`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.ones((5,5), dtype=int)
>>> B = [1, 3, 7, 23]
>>> A.put(B, [0]*len(B))
>>> A
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I was going to ask you to demonstrate your solution with an example, ...wow! you did before I post it. With those examples the idea is now clear. Both methods are helpful.